# Can you write to a file without knowing its complete file path?

Tags: vb.net

In a program I am creating I want to write to a txt file. I know how to do this, however the method I use requires me to know the entire file path of the target file. Is there a way to do this without knowing the entire file path, or, if possible, write to a file located in the project resources?

Comment: There's no such thing as a file located in the project resources. Resources are, by definition, data compiled into the executable itself. The whole point is that they are not files, so they can't be deleted or over-written.

Comment: If you want to access a file then you must be able to specify it's location. You can specify that location relative to some other location that can be variable but the system can know at the current time. For instance, if you want to refer to a file in a subfolder of your program folder then you can use `Application.StartupPath` as the root of the path and just combine your relative path to that. You might look at `Environment.GetFolderPath` and `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` as ways to get various standard paths, e.g. desktop or documents folders.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions:

1. Write the contents of the file to `MemoryStream` and when you know the path of the file write the stream to the file.
2. Write the file contents to a temporary file, and when you know the path of the file, copy the temporary file to the same path